# How to debug FactoInvestigate error: cannot open the connection

Tags: r, pca, multi-factor-authentication

Anyone faced this error:

```
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
```

I was trying to investigate the MCA results using:

```
Investigate(MCA_res, file = "MCA.Rmd", document = c("word_document", "pdf_document"))

> Investigate(MCA_res, file = "MCA.Rmd", document = c("word_document", "pdf_document"))

this hits an error after the following steps:
-- creation of the .Rmd file (time spent : 0s) --
-- detection of outliers (time spent : 0s) --
0 outlier(s) terminated 
-- analysis of the inertia (time spent : 0.08s) --
12 component(s) carrying information : total inertia of 54.3% 
-- components description (time spent : 6.25s) --
plane 1:2 
plane 3:4 
plane 5:6 
plane 7:8 
plane 9:10 
plane 11:12 
-- classification (time spent : 7.04s) --
3 clusters 
-- annexes writing (time spent : 7.24s) --
-- saving data (time spent : 8.83s) --
-- outputs compilation (time spent : 8.83s) --

Quitting from lines 13-15 (MCA.Rmd) 
**Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection**
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (document == "Word" | document == "word" | document == "doc" |  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (document == "html" | document == "HTML" | document == "HTML_document") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (document == "pdf" | document == "PDF") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (document == "word_document") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any help understanding this will be highly appreciated.

Tx
Rj

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the adress of "Workspace.RData" who need to be loaded. I resolve by changing the source: "R/Investigate.R" line 74, writing:

```
writeRmd(paste0("library(FactoMineR)\nload('", getwd(),"/Workspace.RData')"), file = file, start = TRUE, stop = TRUE, options = "r, echo = FALSE")
```

on place of

```
writeRmd"library(FactoMineR)\nload('~/Workspace.RData')"), file = file, start = TRUE, stop = TRUE, options = "r, echo = FALSE")
```